# Could someone provide me with some tips of how I could implement a given algorithm for distributed streaming in Flink?

Tags: state, apache-flink, flink-streaming, data-stream

I'm trying to implement Algorithm 2 (page 4) from this scientific paper ([https://www.cse.ust.hk/~yike/pods10-cdsample.pdf](https://www.cse.ust.hk/%7Eyike/pods10-cdsample.pdf)) in Flink and I would be glad if someone helped me with some tips on how to approach this task (which State should I use, maybe Mapstate?, how to implement broadcast in Flink, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

These algorithms need two-way communication between the coordinator and the workers. To achieve this with the DataStream API you'll need to have some sort of pub-sub channel between the workers and the coordinator so the workers can message the coordinator, and then the coordinator can broadcast its updates out to the workers.

There's an example of how to use Flink's Broadcast State Pattern in https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/flinktraining/examples/datastream_java/broadcast/BroadcastState.java; hopefully that will help you get started.

Alternatively, it might be more natural to implement this use case with Flink's Stateful Functions API. The workers could each register themselves with the coordinator, which could remember their addresses and then message them all as needed.

As for the type of state the coordinator should use, yes, I think MapState is probably the best choice (assuming I've grokked the algorithm approximately correctly).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'm grateful to you! I I'm trying it now.